# Long, single line ES6 string literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The google is full of blog posts and answers to question how one should benefit from ES6 string literals. And almost every blog post explaining this feature in depth has some details on how to implement multiline strings:

```
let a = `foo
bar`;
```

But i can not find any details on how to implement long single line strings like the following:

```
let a = `This is a very long single line string which might be used to display assertion messages or some text. It has much more than 80 symbols so it would take more then one screen in your text editor to view it. Hello ${world}`
```

Any clues or workarounds or should a one stick to the es3 strings instead?

Comment: Are you asking how should you format the code so that it's still a single line but is displayed by the editor over multiple? That has nothing to do with JS or ES6, it's something some editors can do.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv that is true but is it just the editor responsibility solely? For Python i.e. there is PEP8 style guide which suggests not to use lines longer then 80 symbols. Isn't there such guidelines for javascript? How a one should view code with more then 80 lines on github?

Comment: Unfortunately the JavaScript community does'n have its own PEP8. There are various styles and hundreds of style guides. On GitHub you can certainly see code longer than 80 lines, you just need to scroll.

Why do you need to write such a long string anyway? There are maybe workarounds for that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can go on a new line with a string using `\`. The newline character (`\n`) will not appear in the string itself.

```
let a = `This is a very long single line string which might be used \
to display assertion messages or some text. It has much more than \
80 symbols so it would take more then one screen in your text \
editor to view it. Hello ${world}`
```

Pay attention not to indent your string though or the indentation will be in the string:

```
let a = `Hello\
         World`;

a === 'Hello         World' // true
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Gpx answer: you can keep your indentation with [this library](https://github.com/declandewet/common-tags).

```
import {oneLineTrim} from 'common-tags'

oneLineTrim`
  https://news.com/article
  ?utm_source=designernews.com
`)
// https://news.com/article?utm_source=designernews.com
```